# Install NumPy for Python 3.2.3 on OS X 10.7.4

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib, osx-lion, installation

I have been trying for months to get numpy installed for Python 3 but despite copious amounts of Googling and even posting to the numpy mailing list I am still no closer to a solution.

I have managed to get it installed via MacPorts but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a port of MatPlotLib for Python 3 which is the main reason I am trying to install numpy...so I am a bit stuck...

I keep getting the same error whilst trying to build from the setup.py file. I have included the terminal output below.

Thanks for any help you can offer,

Adam.

Here is the terminal output:

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/zj/7xymy_2n3s71ws30v3v_qnlw0000gn/T//ccbRr0Hj.out
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Running from numpy source directory.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 207, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 37, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 169, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 328, in build_extension_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
  File "/Users/adammcnicol/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 410, in generate_config_h
    moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 41, in check_types
    out = check_types(*a, **kw)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 271, in check_types
    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Comment: matplotlib for Python 3 isn't released yet, so it's not surprising that there isn't a port for it. Can you manually install it on top of numpy & py3 from macports?

Comment: I haven't tried via MacPorts yet. I can't get it to install on top of the numpy I have managed to install on top of Python.org Python 3.2.3 (see answer below). I have tried both attempting to install matplotlib from source using build and also the make.osx file. The make.osx file seems to be Python 2 only.

Comment: Have a look at what make.osx is doing - it might be simple to adapt for Python 3.

Comment: I think I have matplotlib installed now! [install matplotlib on Python 3.2/OS X 10.7.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570185/install-matplotlib-1-2-x-on-os-x-lion-10-7-4-and-python-3-2-2/10574470#10574470).

Thanks again, for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to get **NumPy** to install. Not sure it is the best method but it seems to work!

First of all i needed to install **distribute**:

1. `curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python3`

Then I installed **pip**:

1. `curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python3`

After that I had to get **pip** on to my system path (again there are probably better ways):

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Type the following (single line):

   - `sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/pip /usr/local/bin`

With **distribute** and **pip** installed I then installed **Nose**, which NumPy needs for testing or something:

1. Again, in **Terminal** type the following:

   - `pip install nose`

Now I needed to make sure I had the latest version of **Xcode**:

1. From the **AppStore** install the latest version of **Xcode**
2. If you still have a `/Developer` folder then rename it `Developer-old` (not sure whether this will cause problems for me later or not)
3. Open **Terminal** and create a symlink to the AppStore version of Xcode (single line):

   - `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer /Developer`

With all of that out of the way time to install **NumPy**:

1. Download the **NumPy** source from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2rc1/
2. Unarchive the file
3. Open **Terminal** again:

   - `cd` into the directory created by unarchiving the file e.g.

     - `cd /Users/username/Downloads/numpy-1.6.2rc1`
4. Type into the **Terminal** the following to change the complier used to build **NumPy**:

   - `export CC=clang`
   - `export CXX=clang`
   - `export FFLAGS=-ff2c`
   - `export LDSHARED='clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g'` (this is a single line)
   - `python3 setup.py build` (this may take a while)
   - `python3 setup.py install`

Okay, assuming there were no errors **NumPy** should be installed. Time to test it out:

1. Open **IDLE**
2. In the **Python Shell** type:

   - `import numpy`
   - `numpy.test('full')`
3. This will test **NumPy** the final result I received with **Python 3.2.3** was:

   - `<nose.result.TextTestResult run=3192 errors=0 failures=1>`

So the **NumPy** installation passes all except one test, which seems pretty good. I haven't had a chance to see if works properly yet as I am still struggling to get **matplotlib** installed...

Hope these instructions are useful to somebody!

Adam.

Comment: Breaks for me on the python `setup.py build` with message: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Running from numpy source directory.error: Command "clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/numpy/core/src/_sortmodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3 -lnpymath -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/numpy/core/_sort.so" failed with exit status 1` :(

Comment: Try changing the line about sdk from 10.6 to 10.7

Comment: Nope, still blows up.  Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you say to use 1.6.2.rc1 and not just straight 1.6.2 of numpy?

Comment: At the time it was the most recent version.

Comment: For this to work for me on a clean install of OS X 10.8, I had to download XCode as above, then install the Command Line Tools (Preferences->Download) inside XCode before I installed Python 3.3. After installing Python 3.3, I followed the instructions above, but then I downloaded numpy-1.7.0b2 because of its compatibility with Python 3.2. And now I am able to run numpy with Python 3.3 and more importantly with Blender 2.65.

Comment: This failed with the same error as Adam had if I tried it with numpy-1.6.2, but I finally tried numpy-1.7.0rc1 and everything worked fine.  I mention this incase others are trying in van to build numpy-1.6.2 with the MacOSX10.7.sdk from Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Python 3.3 and OS X 10.7, and I installed numpy using a much easier method than above.  I'm posting here in case it can help someone.

Follow these steps:

- Download the zip file from [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) on github, and unpack it wherever you want.
- Open a terminal and cd to the directory
- enter the command `python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95` (requires gfortran.  Enter `gfortran -v` to see if you've got it, I've got version 4.6.2)
- enter `python3 setup.py install`

That's all it took for me.  Running numpy.test('full') gives me some errors, however: http://pastebin.com/5XF0qAe5

I don't know what kind of errors I'm going to experience yet.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer worked great for me, except that you mentioned this was for OS X 10.7 (same here) so my build command did complain about the line:

- export LDSHARED='clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386
  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g' (this is a single line)

So, I just changed that to 10.7 and it worked fine. Apparently, for OS X 10.7, the /Developer/SDKs/ directory contains MacOSX10.7.sdk  and MacOSX10.8.sdk. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've come back to this answer a number of times, if you're using 10.8, you need to do a few things to get this to work (but I don't think you need the LDSHARED part).

1. Install XCode from Apple as well as the command line tools (this gets you the compilers you need).
2. set environment variables to point to `clang` and use `easy_install` (NOT distribute) to install, this line will work:

   CC=clang CXX=clang FFLAGS=-ff2c easy_install numpy
3. Do *not* try to install other packages at the same time. The numpy install may exit claiming an error, but often it manages to install itself anyways (for example, if you try to install in a virtualenv, this may happen).

Answer (score 0):

for me i installed python3 from their website and then to install numpy,

`pip3 install numpy`

it works!