# Curl error while installing numpy and matplotlib for Python 3 on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: curl, numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib, libcurl

Matplotlib has recently [released a python 3 compatible version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib). To install matplotlib, you need numpy.

I was following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2) for installing matplotlib. I tried installing numpy according to the [instructions for Mac OS Lion 10.7 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557857/install-numpy-for-python-3-2-3-on-os-x-10-7-4) (in the hope it might be similar enough), but Terminal got stuck at the first command:

```
$curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python3

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

same for the second one (as expected):

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python3

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

Any ideas for how to fix the curl error?

Comment: Are you sure they have released with Python 3 support? Your link just points to the VCS repository.

Comment: Matplotlib for python3 was originally a separate branch, but it has since been reintegrated into the main branch. This happened within the past few months.

Comment: But a branch isn't a release. A release is whatever the producers, upstream or downstream, call a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?230882-appleseed-renderer-%28now-with-experimental-Blender-exporter!%29&p=2098877&viewfull=1#post2098877), I found instructions to update curl.

But I was concerned about downloading a Mac-safe version, so I went to [this page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), scrolled down to the Mac section and chose one on the Apple website.

In the end I decided to install this version as an additional curl (ie, not replace the system curl), so here are the modified instructions:

1. Download curl sources (link #2)
2. Unarchive the zip file somewhere
3. Open a Terminal window and go to the directory containing curl sources
4. Type: `$CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure --prefix=`*`pathname`*
5. Type: `$make`
6. Type: `$sudo make install`

To run it, cd into the *pathname*/bin/ directory, and run:

```
$ ./curl URL_OF_DOWNLOAD | python3
```