# Numpy in Python 3 on OSX?

Tags: macos, numpy, python-3.x

I'm running Python 3.3 on OSX Lion (10.7), and tried installing `numpy` via pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

This is into a virtual environment created with `virtualenvwrapper`.  However, I get:

```
$ pip install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz (2.6MB): 2.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
    RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
    RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
    RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
    RefactoringTool: Refactored /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy/build/py3k/numpy/__init__.py
    RefactoringTool: Refactored /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy/build/py3k/numpy/_import_tools.py
    RefactoringTool: Refactored /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy/build/py3k/numpy/ctypeslib.py
    RefactoringTool: Refactored /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy/build/py3k/numpy/dual.py

...  MANY LINES OMITTED ....

numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_pywrap.c: In function ânpyiter_ass_subscriptâ:

numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_pywrap.c:2314: warning: passing argument 1 of âPySlice_GetIndicesâ from incompatible pointer type

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/7m/62gtb_jbz4g8g8b5dz046gp17h0168/T//ccyGGQyx.out

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7m/62gtb_jbz4g8g8b5dz046gp17h0168/T/pip-eh07x0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/bin/../include/site/python3.3 failed with error code 1 in /Users/aparkin/.envs/omgwhatverdoiget/build/numpy
Storing complete log in /Users/aparkin/.pip/pip.log
```

Uhm, help?

The full pip.log is at http://pastebin.com/pzdLUM2r (and is rather large -- approx ~6400 lines)

Answer (score 0):

I just refollowed my own instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557857/install-numpy-for-python-3-2-3-on-os-x-10-7-4) when I installed Python 3.3 at the weekend. Seems to be working fine.

Hope this helps,

Adam.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get to `python setup.py build` and get an error message: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Running from numpy source directory.error: Command "clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/numpy/core/src/_sortmodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3 -lnpymath -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.3/numpy/core/_sort.so" failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Try changing the line about sdk from 10.6 to 10.7

Comment: Have you got a /Developer folder? For some reason it doesn't seem to be finding the sdk.

Comment: `$ ls /Developer` gives: 
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  79  1 Oct 13:35 /Developer@ -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/`, so yup.