# installing numpy using python3.2 Mac OSX Lion

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, osx-lion

Trying to build numpy on OSX Lion.
I followed the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557857/install-numpy-for-python-3-2-3-on-os-x-10-7-4?rq=1), using a replacing 10.6 with 10.7 for LDSHARED. However when I run setup.py it seems like it is still using 10.6??

how do i fix this?

```
eric@system-process-2 /Users/Eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2$ export CC=clang
eric@system-process-2 /Users/Eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2$ export CXX=clang
eric@system-process-2 /Users/Eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2$ export FFLAGS=-ff2c
eric@system-process-2 /Users/Eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2$ export LDSHARED='clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -g'
eric@system-process-2 /Users/Eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2$ python3.2 setup.py build
Converting to Python3 via 2to3...
Running from numpy source directory.
non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']

non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']

running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/local/bin/gfortran
Could not locate executable clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -g
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c'
clang: _configtest.c
clang _configtest.o -o _configtest
success!
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c'
clang: _configtest.c
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'exp'
int exp (void);
    ^
_configtest.c:1:5: note: 'exp' is a builtin with type 'double (double)'
1 warning generated.
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'exp'
int exp (void);
    ^
_configtest.c:1:5: note: 'exp' is a builtin with type 'double (double)'
1 warning generated.
clang _configtest.o -o _configtest
success!
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
building library "npysort" sources
building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
Generating build/src.macosx-10.6-intel-3.2/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m -c'
clang: _configtest.c
In file included from _configtest.c:1:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/Python.h:25:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
In file included from _configtest.c:1:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/include/python3.2m/Python.h:25:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 207, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 37, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 169, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 328, in build_extension_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/numpy-1.7.0b2/build/py3k/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 410, in generate_config_h
    moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 41, in check_types
    out = check_types(*a, **kw)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 271, in check_types
    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Met similar problem, and the following command worked for me:

```
export CFLAGS="-isysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk" tox
```